# Is there a way to add a diagonal line pattern through an image of bitmap data?

Tags: flash, actionscript, watermark, bitmapdata

I'm trying to put diagonal lines through an image I have. It's a BitmapData object if that matters.

I'd like the diagonal lines to be white or transparent pixels.

I'm going to tag as watermark because it may be the same principle.

Comment: Create two Bitmap objects. Take image and put into one Bitmap, put line into other Bitmap (bmpData must have transparency channel). `addChild` the Bitmaps into a container Canvas (ie: Sprite) in the order of image BMP followed by line BMP. Anyways there is also a `setPixel` where you can do a for-loop that draws diagnol pixels as the line. Also look into blendModes if you want to overlay watermark-style over another image

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is [a suite of methods `BitmapData` offers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#summaryTableMethod) for coloring pixels, rectangles and even other objects inheriting [`IBitmapDrawable`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/IBitmapDrawable.html) (most inbuilt display objects).

The easiest way would probably be for you to draw the shape you want and then use [`draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw()) to place that shape over the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone giving me direction. So far I've been able to create a diagonal line and repeat it to a variable width and height.

I still need to join the image and lines but I'm calling it a night.

```
var lineBitmapData:BitmapData;
var targetSprite:SpriteVisualElement;
var spriteVE:SpriteVisualElement = new SpriteVisualElement();
var fillSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

// draw our diagonal line on a sprite
fillSprite.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
fillSprite.graphics.moveTo(0, 10);
fillSprite.graphics.lineTo(10, 0);

// draw all the pixels into a bitmap data object 
lineBitmapData = new BitmapData(10, 10, true, 0x000000000000000000);
lineBitmapData.draw(fillSprite);

// create a new sprite and with the graphics object 
// draw a rectangle and fill it with a repeating bitmap data
targetSprite = new SpriteVisualElement();
targetSprite.graphics.beginBitmapFill(lineBitmapData, null, true);
targetSprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
targetSprite.graphics.endFill();

// add 
//targetSprite.blendMode = BlendMode.ERASE;
spriteVE.addChild(targetSprite);

addElement(spriteVE);
```